# Angular $$watchers (sometimes) not being added to manual $compile

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using code of the following nature in a service:

```
var template = '{{error}}' +
               '<form ng-submit="save()">' +
                 '<input ng-model="foo" />' +
                 '<input type="submit value="Save" />' +
               '</form>';

$compile(template)(scope);
```

Which is working some times but not others.  Inspecting the resulting scope, a la

```
angular.element($compile(template)(scope)).scope()
```

sometimes has `$$watchers` and other times doesn't (obviously making it not work when there aren't any).

Why would angular add `$$watchers` some times but not others?

Comment: I think you should compile with one root element try wrapping the entire template with one element eg with a `<div>`. What version of angular, do you have a demo to replicate the problem?

Comment: Sorry, it is in a wrapper div, I just posted that code for simplicity.

Comment: In that case try to replicate it in a demo.

Comment: Yeah, I'll definitely try to replicate it in a demo.  The state is pretty complex, so it might be challenging, but I'll see if I can.